# How can I post multiple users in one form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I want to register an unknown number of users, and would like to avoid having to do a separate form submit per user.

I think I have figured out the view, where I can add and remove rows of users (Thanks to [this](https://shouts.dev/add-or-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery) article).

<del>But I can't seem to get it to bind to the controller POST method. `Users` are returning `null`.</del>

**Update**

Adding `[Bind("Users")]` to the controller method fixed the `null` problem! Now I'm struggeling with the indecies of the rows.

**Update 2**

Solved! Adding `<input type="hidden" name="Users.Index" value="{some unique value}" />` sorts out the indexing problem. I can now consider the index to be non-sequential, and not worry about maintaining the sequence. I have replaced the `lastIndex` introduced in the answer below, with a timestamp. It could be any random number, as long as it is unique to each row in the form.

This is what I have now:

**Models**

```
public class ApplicationUserViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class BatchUserRegistrationViewModel
{
    public List<ApplicationUserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**Create view**

```
@model NameSpace.Models.BatchUserRegistrationViewModel

<form asp-action="RegisterManyUsers">
    @if (Model.Users != null)
    {
        // This part is for when the ModelState is not valid, and POST redirects back to the view.
        // I want the submitted form data to persist.
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count; i++)
        {
            <div id="inputFormRow">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Users.Index" value="@i" />
                    <input type="text" name="users[@i].Email">
                    <input type="text" name="users[@i].FirstName>
                    <input type="text" name="users[@i].LastName">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="removeRow" type="button">
                            (-) Remove row
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // This part is for a new, blank form:
        <div id="inputFormRow">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="hidden" name="Users.Index" value="0" />
                <input type="text" name="users[0].Email">
                <input type="text" name="users[0].FirstName">
                <input type="text" name="users[0].LastName">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="removeRow" type="button">
                        (-) Remove row
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div id="newRow"></div>
    <p>
        <button id="addRow" type="button">
            (+) Add row
        </button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">(v) Register users</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

**Client script**

```
<script>
    // add row
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        let ts = $.now();
        var html = '';
        html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
        html += '    <div class="input-group mb-3">';
        html += '        <input type="hidden" name="Users.Index" value="' + ts + '" />';
        html += '        <input type="text" name="users[' + ts + '].Email">';
        html += '        <input type="text" name="users[' + ts + '].FirstName">';
        html += '        <input type="text" name="users[' + ts + '].LastName">';
        html += '        <div class="input-group-append">';
        html += '            <button id="removeRow" type="button">';
        html += '                (-) Remove row';
        html += '            </button>';
        html += '        </div>';
        html += '    </div>';
        html += '</div>';
        $('#newRow').append(html);
    });

    // remove row
    $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
        $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    });
</script>
```

**Controller POST-method**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterManyUsers([Bind("Users")] BatchUserRegistrationViewModel BatchReg)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (BatchReg.Users != null)
        {
            List<ApplicationUser> dbUsers = new();
            foreach (ApplicationUserViewModel user in BatchReg.Users)
            {
                dbUsers.Add(new ApplicationUser {
                    Email = user.Email,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName
                });
            }
            db.AddRange(dbUsers);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
    return View(BatchReg);
}
```

Comment: the name of the row you are adding is incorrect, it should be users[0].Email

Comment: you can achieve this by defining a global variable in scripts

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<script>
let lastIndex= 0 ;
// add row
$("#addRow").click(function () {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
    html += '    <div class="input-group mb-3">';
    html += '        <input type="text" name="users['+lastIndex+'].Email">';
    html += '        <input type="text" name="users['+lastIndex+'].FirstName">';
    html += '        <input type="text" name="users['+lastIndex+'].LastName">';
    html += '        <div class="input-group-append">';
    html += '            <button id="removeRow" type="button">';
    html += '                (-) Remove row';
    html += '            </button>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '</div>';
    lastIndex=lastIndex+1;
    $('#newRow').append(html);
});

// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    lastIndex=lastIndex-1;
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

Comment: Well, you could be right, but it seems that this is not about what the OP asked.

Comment: @steve well i think the logic is ok, it's just it sends null because of wrong indexing

Comment: The OP complains about POST the whole model as null not a single row. IE the block before the one you are fixing here.

Comment: @fatemehyadollahzadeh This is almost working. Users are stored in the database now. But there is a conflict or mis-match between the index[0] which is in the DOM and the indecies created by the script. If I remove the first row and then submits a list of some rows, the first row is not received by the controller. If I don't remove the first row and just submits that one row, it is received by the controller.

Comment: @Steve I fixed the `null` problem. See updated question.

Comment: @fatemehyadollahzadeh I solved it! Adding `<input type="hidden" name="Users.Index" value="' + lastIndex + '">` did it! Now the index is not sequential, and the content of `lastIndex` could be anything, like a random string or perhaps a microseconds timestamp.